# Exception occurred while executing exported method askAsync on module ExpoPermissions: null

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I'm having an error while using the ExpoPermission interface. I just started to learn about Android development with React and Expo, followed a guide to create a new project

```
npm install -g create-react-native-app 
create-react-native-app my-app 
cd my-app/ 
npm start
```

Everything worked, and the example run on my phone, then i just added a simple button that calls the example from the expo documentation, but it launches this message when i press it.

```
[Error: Encountered an exception while calling native method: Exception occurred while executing exported method askAsync on module ExpoPermissions: null]
```

My code is simple, just added to the view

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={handlePressMe} style={styles.helpLink}>
  <Text style={styles.LinkBlue}>
    Press me!
  </Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Then added the code:

```
function handlePressMe() {
  request_storage_runtime_permission();
}

async function request_storage_runtime_permission() {

  try {
    const granted = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    print(granted)
    Alert.alert("Storage Permission received.");
    /*if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {

      Alert.alert("Storage Permission Granted.");
    }
    else {

      Alert.alert("Storage Permission Not Granted");

    }*/
  } catch (err) {
    console.warn(err)
  }
}
```

And `import * as Permissions from 'expo-permissions';`

I've read the documentation of Expo, and found many installs that said to do for this library, but none has changed anything, just in case, both things i've added

```
sudo expo install expo-permissions
sudo yarn add react-native-unimodules
```

Also to note that i added the permission to app.json, and tried to use getAsync to see if it had been granted, but launched the same error, this is my app.json:

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "Test App",
    "slug": "testApp",
    "privacy": "public",
    "sdkVersion": "35.0.0",
    "platforms": [
      "android",
      "web"
    ],
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/images/icon.png",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/images/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "android": {
      "permissions": [
        "WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Tried searching for more info, but only thing i found are unanswered topics. Does anyone knows what is the problem, or how to prompt more info? Only thing it shows is null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying to do it directly with React Native, i found the problem here:

Expo uses it's own way to name permissions, so if you want to request for WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, while on RN you would call exactly for this permission, on Expo you need to ask for CAMERA_ROLL permission instead, which includes both Write and Read permissions. The error message is little intuitive, since it only marks null, while trying to say that you're sending a null as parameter due to the
 permission that you are requesting (Permissions.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) returning null. So the solution was to change it to:

```
const granted = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA_ROLL);
```

Hope this helps someone on the future.